# Change Text on another Div

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css

Good evening Community,
I have a problem with my code.

HTML:

```
  <a href="aboutme.php">
       <div class='aboutus'>
            <div id="mbubble">
                stuff inside here
            </div>
        </div>
   </a>
   <div id='title'>
        <div class="thome"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text BEFORE</p></div>
        <div class="tabout"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text AFTER</p></div>
```

I want if I hover over the div "mbubble" that the class "thome" will change it's text. I tried to do that by making them visible / invisible.

CSS:

```
#mbubble:hover ~ .thome { visibility:hidden; }
#mbubble:hover ~ .tabout { visibility:visible; }
```

But it's sowhing no affect?

Can you tell me how you would do that? Or at least any way that's working to change the text by hovering?

Best regards,
Michael

Comment: Can't do this with css alone. Will need to use script to toggle classes or change style. The elements are not closely enough related in the dom for any css selector to work

Comment: @charlietfl is right. I would use jQuery and use mouseover functionality

Answer (score 0):

If your structure is really that simple, then a trick with pointer-events could work:

the idea is to kill `pointer-events` on a and reactivate it only on `#mbubble`, since when you hover a child, parent is hovered too, the selector can be taken from the parent .

```css
a {pointer-events:none; }
#mbubble {pointer-events:auto;}
a:hover + #title .thome , .tabout {display:none;}
a:hover + #title .tabout {display:block;}
```

```html
<a href="aboutme.php">
       <div class='aboutus'>i don't trigger anything
            <div id="mbubble">
                I DO
            </div>
        </div>
   </a>
   <div id='title'>
        <div class="thome"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text BEFORE</p></div>
        <div class="tabout"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text AFTER</p></div>
```

**Now, if you realize that without `pointer-events` but only `a;hover` it works , you may understand it can be usefull only if there is other content in `<a>` that should not react . only clicking on `#mbubble` will fire the link.Was your example too little ? if not, just use `a:hover`**

http://caniuse.com/#search=pointer-events

Comment: worth also mentioning that `pointer-events` have limited browser support

Answer (score 0):

How about this:

```
$('#mbubble').hover(function () {   
    $('.thome').html('<p style="letter-spacing:10;">NOW IT IS DIFFERENT</p>');
})
```

Answer (score 0):

It look doable in css, anyway, while not recommmended, there is a quick inline solution in javascript using the transversal DOM, like this:

You got to keep in mind that it can have strange behaviors, non easily copiable by right clicking, this is why inline javascripts should not be used directly. There is workaround around it, good luck.

```html
  <a href="aboutme.php">
       <div class='aboutus'>
            <div onmouseover="document.getElementById('title').children[0].children[0].textContent='Enter the void!'" id="mbubble">
                stuff inside here
            </div>
        </div>
   </a>
   <div id='title'>
        <div class="thome"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text BEFORE</p></div>
        <div class="tabout"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text AFTER</p></div>
```

So a more nicer way is to use a function like this:

```html
  <a href="aboutme.php">
       <div class='aboutus'>
            <div onmouseover="changeText()" id="mbubble">
                stuff inside here
            </div>
        </div>
   </a>
   <div id='title'>
        <div class="thome"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text BEFORE</p></div>
        <div class="tabout"><p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text AFTER</p></div>

        <script>
        function changeText() {
          document.getElementById('title').children[0].children[0].textContent='Enter the void!'
        }
        </script>
```

Still, this isn't clean enough, the good way in javascript is to add an event listener, like this:

```
- 

       <a href="aboutme.php">
           <div class='aboutus'>
               <div id="mbubble">
                   stuff inside here
               </div>
           </div>
       </a>
       <div id='title'>
           <div class="thome">
               <p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text BEFORE</p>
           </div>
           <div class="tabout">
               <p style="letter-spacing:10;">Text AFTER</p>
           </div>
          <script>
           var toBeWatched = document.getElementById('mbubble');
           toBeWatched.addEventListener("mouseover", function(event) {document.getElementById('title').children[0].children[0].textContent
   = 'Enter the void!';setTimeout(function() {  document.getElementById('title').children[0].children[0].textContent 
   = 'Text BEFORE!!!';
               }, 2500);
           }, false);
         </script>
```

This way the html part is left untouched. (..)